# How to change size of tree view without zoom? Odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

here I am again. In first place, sorry for my english. I am not good at this.
Well, I would like to change the size of tree view in odoo 14, in `Work Order`view. The employers need I to increase size because It is too small. Is there a way to increase size of all the view?

Comment: Can you describe more about problem?

Comment: The best solution to this is stick to zoom. Other solutions would involve changing the treeview to add a css class and create the corresponding CSS to increase the font size.

Comment: Hello Bhoomi and Danimar. Bhoomi what I need is to increase the front size and that's why I asked If there is a way to do it

Comment: I have been reading about it and I have not found a way to increase the front size without adding a css class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a css file at path `/your_module/static/src/css/style.css` and put this code in an xml file, which needs to be included in the manifest file also.

```
<odoo>
  <template id="assets_backend" name="3dview assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
      <link type="text/css" href="/your_module/static/src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

After that, you can just craft your CSS file as you require.